# What is Sys() in os.FileInfo?

Tags: go

`os.Stat()` returns [FileInfo](https://golang.org/src/os/types.go?s=479:840#L11) interface, which contains method signature for `Sys()` which have return type of `interface{}`. What is it and, how it can be used.

I tried testing this and it returned a response like [this](https://pastebin.com/8eSqAQ7u), which turns out to be [syscall Stat_t struct](https://golang.org/src/syscall/ztypes_darwin_amd64.go?s=855:1300#L55). But I'm unable to comprehend what is it and how to interfere with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't have to do anything with it. If the information you want about a file is in one of the other FileInfo fields, then use it, and forget about Sys.

In unusual cases, you might want to know some information about a file that's returned by the underlying OS, but isn't populated in FileInfo. In that case you can use the Sys field to access the OS's stat result directly — but you will have to account for the fact that the interface might hold a different type depending on the OS, e.g. a `syscall.Stat` on Unix but a `syscall.Win32FileAttributeData` on Windows.